# Water flowing continuously in toilet

Tags: water, leak, toilet

My toilet bowl is leaking water continuously. See video here: https://youtu.be/khD7VKbWoTo

I cleaned the flapper and put it back, and it doesn't seem to be the issue. Even if I hold the flapper down, the water continues to flow. Any suggestions on what I should try?

Answer (score 6):

That flapper needs to be replaced completely - good news! It's a very cheap part.

Turn the water off to the toilet, remove the flapper, and take it with you to any home parts store of your choice. Pick a flapper of the same size (most universal will work). Once you get a new one in there - turn the water back on.

With a new one it'll seal properly and stop flushing continuously.

Comment: +1; I'll just add to this - where the flapper seats on the PVC ring below it, make sure that surface is not chipped, pitted, or dirty. There's a good chance it is NOT, but if it is, you'd want to buy a service kit and replace both the flapper and the seat to it.